# Huge oil leak but plug still there

Tags: toyota, oil, oil-leak

Just had an issue with my 2008 4runner. The engine light came on, and so I pulled over and checked the oil level.  It seemed to not have any, so I added a quart.  I looked under the car and saw that it was splattered all over the ground.  I checked the oil plug and it is still in place.

Any ideas about what it could be?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it pours straight out when you pour it in, you should be able to see where it is leaking.

So get another quart of oil, place a tray down to catch the leaking oil and pour the new oil in. Now check around the oil filter, oil drain plug, any other sump plugs.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Any ideas as to the severity of the damage?

Comment: If it is just around the filter or sump plug it should be very easy to sort out. Damage-wise, it will depend on how long you ran it with low oil.